# How to make a player die while falling?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a basic game on Unity to improve myself. It's a basic endless runner platform game.

If you right click when the player is on the ground, it jumps; if it's not on the ground, it falls faster.

But I couldn't figure out how to make a player die while falling when it couldn't catch the platform. Could you please check my code? I am trying to find an "if" command to make it happen.

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool onGround;
    float CurrentFallTime;
    public float MaxFallTime = 7;
    bool PlayerIsFalling;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(5, rb.velocity.y);
        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);

        CurrentFallTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && onGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 12);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !onGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -10);
        }

        // I want it to die and go to game over screen when it exceeds the CurrentFallTime
        if ()
        {
            if (CurrentFallTime >= MaxFallTime)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

EDIT: It solved! I simpy added "if(onGround)" and reset the CurrentFallTime. Here is the new code:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool onGround;
    float CurrentFallTime;
    public float MaxFallTime = 7;
    bool PlayerIsFalling;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(5, rb.velocity.y);
        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);

        CurrentFallTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (onGround)
        {
            CurrentFallTime = 0f;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && onGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 12);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !onGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -10);
        }



        if (CurrentFallTime >= MaxFallTime)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it! Can you post the fix as an answer (you can answer your own questions) for easier reference?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I just thought of now, so I'm not sure how well it will work, but you can create a 1-sided plane collider and position it to follow the x- and y-coordinate of the player, but stay slightly lower than the height of the ground, e.g. 1unit. Then check when the player collides with the plane, if it does then you know that the player has fallen.

So, create an empty GameObject and add the collider, no need for any mesh properties and set the collider trigger to true. Then in player controls add something like in update.

```
colliderGo.transform.location = new Vector3(transform.x, groundHeight - 1, transform.z)
```

Also in the player controller function

```
function onTrigger(Collider col) {
    if (col.tag == "fallDetector") {
        Debug.Log("What a cruel world")
        playHasFallen = true;
    }
}
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Hello, I am planning to write an if statement rather than adding a collider. My plan is to add something like that;

 if (Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -10) && !onGround) { if (CurrentFallTime >= MaxFallTime) { SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver"); } }

 But I can't write Vector in an if statement :(